# Modsecurity Rule that Would Block the IP After a Certain Amount of 403 Errors

Tags: apache2, mod-security, ip-blocking

I am trying to figure out how to write a **ModSecurity** rule that would block the IP from the server for a period of time when that IP is generating a certain amount of 403 errors, and I am struggling with writing the rule. Does anyone have any ideas of what this rule would look like?

Comment: I recommend you take a look at the OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set (CRS) to get an idea for how rules are written. Combined with the ModSecurity documentation, you should be able to figure out how to create variables, how to increment the variable per 403 response, and how to block the IP once that variable hits your desired threshold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fail2Ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/) is the correct tool for this. It can read ModSecurity logs and ban IP addresses based on them. It comes with a [filter](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/master/config/filter.d/apache-modsecurity.conf) for ModSecurity 2 that can be enabled in, e.g., `/etc/fail2ban/jail.d/apache.conf`:

```
[apache-modsecurity]
enabled = true
```

You might want to adjust the `maxretry` as it defaults to `2` which seems pretty aggressive.

Comment: Does fail2ban work on windows ?

Comment: How to do that on windows with IIS ?

Comment: @KhurshidAlam Let me google that for you! With `Fail2Ban for Windows` the first results says: "Fail2ban is not available for Windows but there are some alternatives that runs on Windows with similar functionality."